# Problemas con CSRF Token en Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, python-requests, tokens

Estoy realizando un proyecto el cual consta de crear una API que crea un usuario luego de recibir una petición.

La peticion la hago a través del siguiente código:

data = {
'celular': number
}

```
    api_url = 'http://localhost:8000/users/create-user/'

    response = requests.post(api_url, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print('Usuario creado con exito')
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        print('Error en la solicitud')
```

Y luego, en la API tengo la siguiente vista:

```
class UserCreate(APIView):
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def post(self, request):
    csrf_token = request.COOKIES.get('csrftoken')

    if not csrf_token:
        return Response({"error": "CSRF token missing"}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    response = Response()

    serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Al hacer el llamado, me tira el siguiente error desde la API:

```
chatbot_local_django        | Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /users/create-user/
chatbot_local_django        | WARNING 2023-10-28 10:53:25,608 log 21 140269942036224 Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /users/create-user/
chatbot_local_django        | INFO:     172.20.0.1:50500 - "POST /users/create-user/ HTTP/1.1" 403 Forbidden
```

Como puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Aclaro que el código que tengo en la vista me lo dio ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasa lo mismo, creo que es un problema del frontend. Con algo de cookies.
Fijate si tenes este middleware  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

Comment: si tenes idea de como se soluciona y quieres darme una mano soy todo oídos

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/406415)